# How to connect MySQL database using C# for a log in validation?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been stuck on this for a couple of days now and I can't seem to find a solution. I am trying to connect to a MySQL database and validate a user for a login page using C# ASP.NET and MVC4. Here's the code I'm trying to use. The debugger gives me the error at at the MysqlDataReader line. The error I get is:

Stored Procedure is:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetUser`(
in search varchar (200))
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM GetUser
WHERE id;

END
```

.

```
public bool isValid(string username, string password) // Used to validate user
    {
        using (MySqlConnection connection = DBConnect.getconnection())
        {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("GetUser", connection))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?search", MySqlDbType.VarChar));

                    cmd.Parameters["?search"].Value = "%" + "" + "%";
                    cmd.Parameters["?search"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;


                    MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    if (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("Index");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("LogIn");
                    }
                }

        }

        bool isValid = false;

        return isValid;
    }
```

The error I get is:

`An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll but was not handled in user code`

`Additional information: Table 'systemusers.getuser' doesn't exist`

Comment: can you update the question with `GetUser` stored procedure code?

Comment: what is `search` parameter? you haven't give any value for that

Comment: I updated it with the stored procedure and some new code

Comment: create stored procedure to accept username and password as parameter, and select records by those parameters in where condition.

Comment: Sorry, but Im still fairly new to this but is this what you mean within the parameters? "Select * from GetUser where username=?username and password=?password"

Comment: What is the name of the database table where the user records are stored?  Your stored procedure is written as if the name of the *table* is "GetUser" but the error message is indicating that this is not the case.